# Is there an alternative to startActivity()?

Tags: android

I am making my first android application, and it requires switching between activities very frequently. I know I can call finish() to end the current Activity, but I was wondering if there was a way to not call finish() or startActivity(), but to somehow return to the old instance of that Activity? Not using the back button either.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`  it will clear all the activity till previous reference of this OLD_ACTIVITY.

use the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` with your intent. For more detail -

```
Intent i =new Intent(current_ACTIVITY.this, OLD_ACTIVITY.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

there are more Flag like NO_History and more...........

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand I would suggest that you use `startActivityForResult()` to launch a new activity and then on finish of the new activity you will get back to the old instance of the previous activity.